# javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch! when password.length >= 16

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am newbie in regards to AES encryption/decryption.
I found the following nice article from Michael Remijan
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/12/choosing-java-cryptographic-algorithms-part-2-single-key-symmetric-encryption.html

I have tried the example tests, and it runs just fine whith smaller length passwords.
However when I change the length of the message (password) string to a length >= 16 it fails with the following exception.

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:578)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1049)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:985)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2047)
```

I have contacted Michael about this issue, yet he does not currently know why this behaviour occurs.

However I recently just found a fix for this but I unfortunately do not understand why. I hope you guys can help here :-)

The fix looks like this and is to be found in the encrypt method of the Aes class.
The original encrypt method in the Aes class (from the article) contains the following :

```
public byte[] encrypt(String message, Optional<String> aad) {
......
// Add message to encrypt
c.update(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      
// Encrypt
byte[] encryptedBytes = c.doFinal();
//....
```

I changed it to this :

```
public byte[] encrypt(String message, Optional<String> aad) {
.....
// Add message to encrypt
// REMOVE THIS c.update(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        
// Encrypt
byte[] encryptedBytes = c.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
.....
```

and it works :-) but why ?

Thanks alot.

Comment: You must of course concatenate the return values of the `update()` and `doFinal()` calls. In the current case the return value of the `update()` call is simply ignored.

Comment: For a plaintext smaller than a block it works, because `update()` returns nothing for this case, but only `doFinal()`. See the functionality of [`update()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update(byte%5B%5D)) and [`final()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal(byte%5B%5D)).

Comment: Sorry Topaco - thanks for your clarifications by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my original blog post to fix the error Peter found.

https://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2017/12/choosing-java-cryptographic-algorithms_22.html

For demonstration purposes, I made my `Aes` class abstract with two new concrete classes which extend it:

1. [AesUsingSinglePartEncryption.java](https://github.com/mjremijan/thoth-cryptography/blob/master/thoth-cryptography-03-encryption-symmetric-aes256/src/main/java/org/thoth/crypto/symmetric/AesUsingSinglePartEncryption.java) - Demonstrates the single-part encryption operation, which uses a single call to `Cipher#doFinal(byte[])` to get the encrypted bytes.
2. [AesUsingMultiplePartEncryption.java](https://github.com/mjremijan/thoth-cryptography/blob/master/thoth-cryptography-03-encryption-symmetric-aes256/src/main/java/org/thoth/crypto/symmetric/AesUsingMultiplePartEncryption.java) - Demonstrates the multiple-part encryption operation which makes multiple calls to `Cipher#update(byte[])` and then a final call to `Cipher#doFinal()`. All the encrypted bytes are store along the way and returned after the call to `Cipher#doFinal()`.

This solves the problem and demonstrates two different ways of using `Cipher` to get encrypted bytes.

Comment: Nice :-) 
Sorry cant give you a thumbs up on this... too low of a reputation score :-)
I will have a look at your updated code. Thanks for sharing.